# master/detail actionbar fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, master-detail

I have found this https://github.com/abidk/android_masterdetail_tab_issue and it is exactly the base for my app, great work from abidk. It executes perfect on tablet and adding more fragments is very easy but on phone it is producing an error: what could be the reason and how to fix it?

```
D/dalvikvm(3695): Late-enabling CheckJNI
D/AndroidRuntime(3695): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(3695): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b192a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example.masterdetail_tabs/com.example.example.masterdetail_tabs.ItemListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at com.example.example.masterdetail_tabs.Tab1Fragment.onCreateView(Tab1Fragment.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5056)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(3695): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.example.masterdetail_tabs.ItemListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     ... 20 more
I/Process(3695): Sending signal. PID: 3695 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `layout` folders? Which Android versions are the tablet and the phone on?

Comment: Both are Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" 4.1.2 and Galaxy III mini 4.1.2. Only one layout folder. I used the original code that is on github

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your code but it looks like you inherited or imported the wrong `Fragment` for either your ItemListFragment or the Activity using it.

Your logcat shows the exception as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.example.masterdetail_tabs.ItemListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Check your usages and imports etc

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 vs
import android.app.Fragment
```

Also be mindful of which variants of Activity and Fragment can make use of which types and are compatible with which versions of the API. You should read and follow the [official Android tutorial on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) for further info and proper usages.

Comment: The code is the original code that is on github. I have not modified this.

Comment: The original author has used mixed versions in their code too then. Read through the tutorial I think in my answer to decide yourself which version you want to use (support.v4, support.v7 or latest) and modify the imports & inheritances appropriately.

Comment: I just looked at the code on github. It's a mess. The author has indeed mixed the various Fragment implementations. It's curious that it works on one device, but not another... but that's neither here nor there. The code will eventually crash, and has.